# Making CustomView scrollable

Tags: android, android-custom-view, scrollable

I have made a Custom View called a CounterWidget. The digits of a given number are showed in separate rectangular boxes(commas included), as shown in the image. With small numbers, the rendering is just fine. But in the case of large numbers(very large), the rendering is larger than the size of the screen and a few of the rectangular boxes go out of the screen. To counter that, I want to make this custom view scrollable. How can I make this custom view scrollable.

Given below is the image for the custom view rendered :

[image]

Also, if the number is too large the rendering goes out of the screen, as shown below:

[image]

This problem needs to be countered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a horizontal scroll view like

```
<HorizontalScrollView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    >

  // code for CounterWidget   

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: This would be if I declare the CounterWidget inside a horizontal scroll view. Whereas, I wanted to make the view of the CounterWidget scrollable internally. I don't want to declare a separate scrollview.

Comment: if you are making counterwidget dynamically then use horizontallscrollview.addview(counterwidget); to make a scroll view

Answer (score 0):

Put the CustomView inside a [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) in your layout.

Comment: This would be if I declare the CounterWidget inside a horizontal scroll view. Whereas, I wanted to make the view of the CounterWidget scrollable internally. I don't want to declare a separate scrollview.